# I am receiving a "user-type not defined" error when defining variables

Tags: vba, excel

The code below is used at the beginning of my function. I am merely defining a cell containing a number as a variable in order to reduce the amount of typing later in my code. I'm confused as my variable type is nothing special, just a good ole number..

```
Sub PECcalc()

Dim pu238 As [Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(4, 6).Value]
Dim pu241 As [Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(5, 6).Value]
Dim am241 As [Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(6, 6).Value]
Dim pu238PEC As [Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(2, 2).Value]
Dim pu239PEC As [Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(3, 2).Value]
Dim pu240PEC As [Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(4, 2).Value]
Dim pu241PEC As [Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(5, 2).Value]
Dim am241PEC As [Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(6, 2).Value]
Dim np237PEC As [Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(7, 2).Value]
Dim u328PEC As [Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(8, 2).Value]
Dim u235PEC As [Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(9, 2).Value]
```

Comment: `Dim pu238 As 123.231` (assuming the cell contained 123.231) makes no sense - try `Dim pu238 As Double : pu238 = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(4, 6).Value`

Comment: That fixes the first 3 but the following line 

`Dim pu238PEC As Double: pu238PEC [Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(2, 2).Value] `

gives me the error "Complile error: Expected Sub, Function, or Property"

Comment: `Dim pu238PEC As Double: pu238PEC [Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(2, 2).Value]` should have been written in a similar way to the first three - i.e. `Dim pu238PEC As Double: pu238PEC = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(2, 2).Value`

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub PECcalc()

    Dim pu238 As Double
    pu238 = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(4, 6).Value

    Dim pu241 As Double
    pu241 = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(5, 6).Value

    Dim am241 As Double
    am241 = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(6, 6).Value

    Dim pu238PEC As Double
    pu238PEC = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(2, 2).Value

    Dim pu239PEC As Double
    pu239PEC = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(3, 2).Value

    Dim pu240PEC As Double
    pu240PEC = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(4, 2).Value

    Dim pu241PEC As Double
    pu241PEC = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(5, 2).Value

    Dim am241PEC As Double
    am241PEC = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(6, 2).Value

    Dim np237PEC As  Double
    np237PEC = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(7, 2).Value

    Dim u328PEC As Double
    u328PEC = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(8, 2).Value

    Dim u235PEC As Double
    u235PEC =  Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(9, 2).Value
    '...etc
```

or the other style:

```
Sub PECcalc()

    Dim pu238 As Double
    Dim pu241 As Double
    Dim am241 As Double
    Dim pu238PEC As Double
    Dim pu239PEC As Double
    Dim pu240PEC As Double
    Dim pu241PEC As Double
    Dim am241PEC As Double
    Dim np237PEC As  Double
    Dim u328PEC As Double
    Dim u235PEC As Double

    pu238 = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(4, 6).Value
    pu241 = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(5, 6).Value
    am241 = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(6, 6).Value
    pu238PEC = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(2, 2).Value
    pu239PEC = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(3, 2).Value
    pu240PEC = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(4, 2).Value
    pu241PEC = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(5, 2).Value
    am241PEC = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(6, 2).Value
    np237PEC = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(7, 2).Value
    u328PEC = Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(8, 2).Value
    u235PEC =  Worksheets("PEC Conversion").Cells(9, 2).Value
    '...etc
```

Comment: Please do away with the square brackets and benefit from compile-time validation of whatever you put between `[` and `]`. Square-bracketed expressions are just shorthand for `Application.Evaluate`. Systematically using them is outright dangerous, someone should point it out.

Comment: Do the values need to be in brackets as well? Edit: Was gonna say... what's the purpose of the brackets??

Comment: @Harry if any of these cells contains an error value (e.g. `#VALUE!` or `#REF!`), that's the error you'll get, yes. Error values can't be assigned to a `Double`. Or anything other than a `Variant` for that matter. Use the `IsError` function to determine if it's legal to assign it to a `Double`.

Comment: @Harry – square brackets removed, code works well for me.

Comment: I'm very new to the syntax of vba. I was not sure about the brackets but it solved an error I had the other day. thank you for the heads up!

Comment: Also @Mat'sMug I currently have an IsError but no until later in my code. Removing brackets fixed this issue. Running into some more issues but I want to give them a go myself. Thanks!